# Assign variable to a file downloaded via curl with origin filename preserved

Tags: bash, variable, curl

I have looked through several examples but I cannot find what I need.  I am trying to dynamically assign the name of a file I am downloading to a variable so that I can refer to it later.  I have to preserve the origin filename as this is hard-coded in the sha256 checksum file that I am subsequently using to validate the file integrity.

```
URL="https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country-CSV&license_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&suffix=zip"
```

`curl -s -J "$URL"`

obviously I cannot just go: `filename=$(curl -s -J "$URL")` as that would just assign the file contents.

Any Pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the solution using the `curl --write-out` variables:

```bsh
# filename=$(curl -s -O -J -w '%{filename_effective}' "https://download.maxmind.com/app/geoip_download?edition_id=GeoLite2-Country-CSV&license_key=xxxxxxxxxx&suffix=zip" | awk {'print $1'})

# echo $filename
GeoLite2-Country-CSV_20220329.zip
```